# How to set/get a global variable between an AudioPlaybackAgent in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-audio

I'm trying to make a small radius with the `AudioPlaybackAgent` as Microsoft show in their [Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) In the sample we have a list of adudios:

```
private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://000.000.000.000/radio1.mp3", UriKind.Absolute),
    "Radio 1", null, null, null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.Pause),

    new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://000.000.000.000/radio2.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
    "Radio 2", null, null, null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.Pause)
};
```

And here I would play the tracks:

```
private void PlayTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
{
    player.Track = _playList[VARIABLE];
}
```

On "VARIABLE" I want to put a variable that change depending the page I open in the main project. How I can do it? I tried a lot of things without exit. Thnks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer: If you not need to use the audio in background you can simple use the media element, but if you want to use it you CAN NOT interactuate between the background agent and the main project with public variables, you must be work with Tag property of the audio player to store and get data, if this don't work you can try IsolatedStorge - Mutex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play music based on what page the user is viewing, you should use the MediaElement control instead of an audio agent. You can set the source of the MediaElement to be whatever you want. You can do this is XAML or code

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaElement" Source="{Binding YourProperty}"/>

MyMediaElement.Source = new Uri(model.YourProperty);
MyMediaElement.Volume = 1;
MyMediaElement.Play();
```

You can also set the track for the BackgroundAudioPlayer from your application

```
var track = new AudioTrack(
        new Uri(AudioUri),
        "Some song",   // can be an empty string if no song title
        "Some artist", // can be an empty string if no artist name
        null, // album
        null, // album art
        );

BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = track;
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
```

Comment: Yes but I think I can't listen it on the background, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. But do you need it to play on the background? Playing on the background is for when you want the music to continue to play even after the user has exited your app

Comment: Yes I know. As I see, I can't do it. I need to do it through an IsolatedStorage. http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/106035/624934.aspx#624934 Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not entirely true. You can interact with the BackgroundAudioPlayer object from your page and edit the track from your page. It comes down to do you need background audio (have same audio play when navigate away from page) and do you need to play different songs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Could you give me an example please? You mean I have to change "the track" depending on the page I open or what. Sorry for me low knoledge.